# System.IO.IOException thrown when trying to get file names

Tags: c#-4.0, networking, ioexception

I'm trying to calculate the total size of all the files in which last write time is earlier than 10 minutes from now in a specified directory *which has a large amount of data*. Here goes the code I've tried below:

```
DateTime from_date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10);
List<string> list = Directory.GetFiles(@[PATH], "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)               
            .Where(x => File.GetLastWriteTime(x).Date > from_date)
            .Select(x => new FileInfo(x).FullName)
            .ToList();            

foreach (String s in list)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(s);
    size += file.Length;
}

button6.Text = ((size / 1024f) / 1024f) + "MB";
```

This works when I specify a **local** path, but throws me a **Network name no longer available** IOException when specifying a network path. Why does it happen? Is there a way where I can kind of "hold" the network path or make sure the connection to this path will not fail?

Comment: Sounds like a cranky network problem to me.  File server goes off line, login expired, that sort of thing.  Talk to the LAN admin.  Always use the much better DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles() method in .NET 4.0.

Comment: @HansPassant Why DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles() is much better? What is the difference? Will I be able to use something close to SearchOption.AllDirectories on it?

Comment: It doesn't make round-trips back and forth to the server.  So it is a *lot* quicker, you can use that if your network is unstable :)  DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories has an AllDirectories option.  Btw, looks like you really ought to use FileSystemWatcher instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()` and `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories` are the best option.

```
var directories = new DirectoryInfo(root).EnumerateDirectories().OrderByDescending(d => d.Name);
IEnumerable<FileInfo> files;

foreach (DirectoryInfo directoryInfo in directories)
{
    files = directoryInfo
        .EnumerateFiles("*" + extension, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime);
    foreach (FileInfo f in files)
    {
        if ((f.LastWriteTime.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10)) == 1)
        {
            // Do whatever you want with the files
        }
    }
}
```